# how to get all of the implemantations of an Interface using Reflection?

Tags: c#, inheritance, reflection, interface, implementation

```
Public interface IRuleObject {}

Public class RuleBase : IRuleObject {}

Public class Length : RuleBase {}

Public class Range : RuleBase {}

Public class SetDefault : IRuleObject {}
```

I'm trying to write a piece of code in which I can get all of the classes that implement
IRuleObject...

As you noticed, some **Rules** might be derived from **RuleBase** which implements the **IRuleObject** and there are some other **Rules** which don't inherit the **RuleBase** and try implement the **IRuleObject** on their own. All of the **Rules** above are assignable to **IRuleObject**.

I tried :

```
Assembly dll = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IRuleObject));
var rules = dll.GetTypes().Where(x => x.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IRuleObject)));
```

However it couldn't retrieve the **Rules**
ideas are appreciated :-)
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've just got IsAssignableFrom the wrong way round. Try:

```
var rules = dll.GetTypes()
               .Where(x => typeof(IRuleObject).IsAssignableFrom(x));
```

This sort of thing gets a *lot* trickier when generics are involved, but in your case it should be simple enough.

Comment: Thanks Jon, as always you are the savior :-)